# I've a field which is not primary key id. how can i fetch data using JPA repository through that non primary key?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've a model User. There's a field which is contact and it's a non primary key. How can i fetch data using this key? it's an unique key.

This is my model.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
long userId;

@Column(name = "name")
String name;

@Column(name = "email")
String email;

@Column(name = "contact")
String contact;

@Column(name = "category")
String category;

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public User() {
}

}
```

This is the method inside Service layer.

```
public User getUserByContact(String contact) {
        Optional<User> result = userRepository.findByContact(contact);
        User user = result.get();
        return user;
    }
```

This is the repository.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select u from User u where u.contact = ?1")
    User findByContact(String contact);
}
```

I'm getting an error on "select u from User u where u.contact = ?1" this portion under User and it's saying "cant resolve symbol User". Would appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: Can't remember if it is the same in Spring Boot but normally, we use the "as" keyword in an alias case, which means, "select u from User as u where u.contact = ?1" in your case

Comment: getting the same error

Comment: BTW, why do you need the Query part..? The whole concept of JPA is that it can understand it by itself by the time you use the correct column/field name. I guess you do not need Query at all before findByContact(String contact)

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the @Query part, that part is not needed if you extend a JpaRepository. [As stated in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details) JPA derives the query from the method name.
I'm not sure whether this is an issue, but in your entity class you use a `long` for id and in your repository definition (`JpaRepository<User, Long>`) you use a `Long`. Correct me if this is not problematic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use @Query, then the right approach would be to use @Param to define the variable

@Query("select u from User u where u.contact = :contactVar ", nativeQuery = true)
User findByContact(@Param("contactVar")String contactVar);